# LC 3 program not displaying output

Tags: loops, char, lc3

I am trying to write an lc 3 assembly language program that reads in a string and outputs the string. Now I am pretty confused as to why the program wont output anything. I am not sure if my algorithm to store the string in memory is incorrect or if I am just not displaying the string properly. The error is telling me "expected label or 9 bit signed pc offset but found lea instead. So this means it doesnt want me using lea right? But im not sure what else to use. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
.ORIG X3000

LEA R0, prompt
PUTS

LEA R1,SPACE
loop:
GETC               ; input char
PUTC               ; store char
STR R0,R1,#0       ; store r1 in r0
ADD R1,R1,#1       ; points to next block
br loop

ld      r7,eol     ;check for eol 
add     r7,r7,r0  
brz 
lea r0,SPACE       ;displays output
puts

halt

;*************data**********************

SPACE  .blkw   20   
prompt .stringz "input string>> "
eol  .fill   xfff6

.end
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error lies within this line of code

`brz 
lea r0,SPACE       ;displays output`

You use a BR instruction without a label to jump to? Where do you want to branch to if the branch is taken.

Also your code has an infinite loop within it.  You Bracnh back to loop unconditionally, before checking if you got an eol character.